# Concatenate a number N of fields dynamically in SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query in bigquery with several fields, the number of fields can vary in each table, what I want is to obtain that data as a concatenated STRING.

This is what I have:

```
select 
  concat(
    IFNULL(field1,'NULL'), '@',
    IFNULL(field2,'NULL'), '@',
    IFNULL(field3,'NULL')
  ) as fieldsUnion
from MY_DATASET.TABLE_ONE
limit 1
```

This is the result:

```
NULL@data2@data3
```

Is it possible to generate this concatenation regardless of the number of the field to collect and without having to repeat the IFNULL function in each field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```
select *, replace(trim(format('%t', t), '()'), ', ', '@') fieldsUnion
from `MY_DATASET.TABLE_ONE` t
```

with output like

[image]

above approach assumes that there is no `,` (comma+space) within the column value

To address this, you can use below one

```
select *, (
  select string_agg(trim(val, '"'), '@' order by offset)
  from unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"[^"]+":("[^"]+"|null)')) val with offset
) fieldsUnion
from `MY_DATASET.TABLE_ONE` t
```

with below output

[image]

Comment: It is possible to use this method as a separate procedure, that is, first I generate an ARRAY with the fields that I want to concatenate and then I pass the ARRAY to the procedure that returns the concatenated fields, without the need to do a select on the table.

Comment: i think it is doable - not proc but rather udf